# How to add default field created, created by in SharePoint page layout

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi i tried creating new article page layout using content type and design manager and i want to add the default field created and created by after the title field.

When i edit the page layout html page i cannot find it.

```
 <div>
        <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldTextField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">-->
            <!--MS:<PageFieldTextField:TextField FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
            <!--ME:</PageFieldTextField:TextField>-->
        <!--ME:</Publishing:EditModePanel>-->
        <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
    </div>
    <div>
        <!--CS: Start Page Field: Article Date Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldDateTimeField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--MS:<PageFieldDateTimeField:DateTimeField FieldName="71316cea-40a0-49f3-8659-f0cefdbdbd4f" runat="server">-->
            <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
        <!--ME:</PageFieldDateTimeField:DateTimeField>-->
        <!--CE: End Page Field: Article Date Snippet-->
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Created` and `Created By` field are the system fields, which cannot be edited.
System captures this information. You can have this fields in view form. But on Edit Form you cannot add these field. These are read only fields.

All System fields or the custom fields which are marked as **read only** cannot be found on edit or new page.

Note: Even `Modified` and `Modified By` fields are also read only and cannot be made available on New/Edit form.